# What does "flash to sugar" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Mank* (2020), Marion Davies visited Mank at his house in her car. They went out for a drink to have a chat. Mank is drinking wine:

> Marion Davies: Drink it fast. In this heat, it'll **flash to sugar**.

What does "flash to sugar" mean ?

Comment: Maybe she is joking that the alcohol in the wine will evaporate, leaving sugar?

Comment: Marion Davies was an actress, so she was probably more concerned about not getting fat than most. Perhaps she was aware that alcohol is high in calories ***like*** sugar, and mistakenly assumed that the mechanism by which this happens involves converting alcohol into sugar, which *then* leads to weight gain. Same as heating starch (bread, potatoes, etc.) causes ***hydrolysis*** - converting the starch into simple sugars which the body can then absorb (potentially leading to "unwanted-for-actresses" weight gain).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That doesn't really make sense - the drink would have the same sugar content before and after it evaporated.

Comment: @Astralbee: The idea that you'd be left with just sugar after the *evaporation* of a glass of wine doesn't make much sense either. I doubt the solids left after 100% evaporation would amount to even 1 gram, and hardly any of that would be "sugar" anyway. But I'm assuming Marion Davies wasn't much of a material scientist / chemist!

Comment: ...anyway, I suggested she might be assuming the mere application of heat (cooking or hot sun) might turn energy-giving alcohol into sugar, same as heat turns starch into sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flash) gives this definition for 'flash':

> 6. to change suddenly or violently into **vapor**

In other words, *e**vapor**ate*. She is saying that the heat could evaporate the drink and suddenly change it to sugar. This is, of course, an exaggeration for the purpose of humour, but most alcoholic drinks contain sugars - wines range from 0 to 220 grams of sugar per litre.

Comment: I wonder if it's a possible meaning that the alcohol could combust in the heat, rather than evaporate.

Comment: @StuartF I doubt it, when there's such a direct definition. One wouldn't use a word that has a primary meaning in the context and hope your listeners assume some secondary meaning (unless it was some vulgar double-entendre which people always seem to notice). Also, if it set alight, the sugar wouldn't remain.